# Adding acra.jar to the /libs folder

Tags: android, acra

I am trying to use ACRA in my helloacra android applications.

I read this [article](http://acra.googlecode.com/svn-history/r829/wiki/BasicSetup.wiki) .

There it is written "Add the `acra-4.2.3.jar` from the archive (acra-4.2.3/build) in the `libs` folder"

But the file is being added to the "referenced libraries" instead (acra-4.2.3.jar)

I tried to move it to the libs folder but could not.

Please advise...

TIA

Guy

Comment: "but could not" is a useless explanation of your problem. Please consider editing your question to explain *precisely* what you are trying and what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you add any library to the `/libs` folder, the newer versions of ADT automatically add it to your build path. This is why you're also seeing it in `Referenced Libraries`. This is perfectly normal and expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!
So I can see it in Referenced Libraries but not in /Libs as it is said in the article - and you say its ok ....

Comment: What do you mean you can't see it there?

Comment: the libs folder contains only 1 file : android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Did you copy paste acra into the folder?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh.
Ok here is what I did now (for the benefit of all):
1. Using build path, I made sure that there is no reference for acra.jar
2. I dragged and dropped the file again to the libs folder! 
3. I added it to the build path

THanks again Raghav for re-answering!!!!!

Comment: I think it was present earlier as well, but that you copied it to the libs folder using Windows Explorer or Finder instead of Eclipse. Due to this, it was compiled into your app, but Eclipse didn't show it in the project navigator

Comment: I dragged and dropped the file from windows explorer to the libs folder.... 

worked like magic :)